# give an example such that the strict inequalities $\int_E \liminf f_n < \liminf \int_E f_n < \limsup \int_E f_n < \int \limsup f_n$ hold

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, lebesgue-integral

Give an example of a sequence of measurable functions $\{f_n\}$ defined on a measurable set $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ such that the following strict inequalities hold:
\begin{align}
\int_E \liminf f_n < \liminf \int_E f_n < \limsup \int_E f_n < \int \limsup f_n. 
\end{align}

MY ATTEMPT : Take $f_n = \chi_{[n, n+1]}$, then $\liminf f_n = 0$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n= 1$, so we have $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \liminf f_n = 0 < 1 = \liminf \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n$. But $\liminf \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n = \limsup \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n$ still holds.

Can anyone give me some examples please?

Comment: That essentially means we need to find a sequence of function that does not converge. Also, we need to make sure that the sequence of the integral also does not converge. This is the idea.

Comment: Yes, but what are the specific examples?

Comment: I will let you know if I can construct an example.

Comment: Okay, thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E=[0,3]$ and consider 
$$
f_n
\begin{cases}
\chi_{[0,2]} & \text{ if } n \text{ is even},\\
\chi_{[2,3]} &\text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then, 
$$\liminf_{n\to +\infty} f_n = 0 \qquad\text{and}\qquad \limsup_{n\to +\infty} f_n = 1,$$
which implies 
$$
\int_0^3 \liminf_{n\to +\infty} f_n = 0 \qquad \text{and}\qquad \int_0^3\limsup_{n\to +\infty} f_n = 3.
$$
Moreover,
$$ \int_0^3 f_n(x)\,dx = \begin{cases}
2 & \text{ if } n \text{ is even},\\
1 &\text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$
Hence, 
$$
\liminf_{n\to+\infty} \int_0^3 f_n(x)\,dx = 1 \qquad \text{and}\qquad \limsup_{n\to+\infty}\int_0^3 f_n(x)\,dx = 2.
$$